# Scipy.optimization finding unknown parameters between two sets of data describing the same rotation

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have two sets, R1 and R2, of  data which both represent the same rotations in different coordinate systems. They are not equally sampled, so I have alot more samples in R1 than R2 for the same time span. There is a also a time delay between the sets. So a rotation at time t in R1 can be found at time t' = t + delta in R2.

I want to find this time delay and also the unknown transformation between the coordinate systems (Which I assume is a pure rotation)

So I start by interpolating the R1 data set using spherical interpolation (SLERP). I then multiply it by R, which is the transformation matrix, so the rotations are now expressed in the same coordinate system. I then rotate the whole thing back with the transpose (same as inverse for rotation matrices) of R2, which should generate an identity matrix if R1 and R2 describes the same rotation.

I've used this cost function

```
def cost_func(x,R1,R2)  

    R = x[1:].reshape(3,3)
    time_delay = x[0]

    For n in range(R2)

        Rtot = transpose(R2)*R*SLERP(R1,time_delay)
        alpha[n] = rotation_matrix_to_axis_angle(Rtot)

    return alpha**2
```

and then tried both scipy.optimize.fmin and scipy.optimize.leastsq.

```
optimize.fmin(cost_func,initial_guess,args=(R1,R2))
```

I get very good values for the time delay when I try with synthetic data, but I do not get very accurate values for the transformation matrix. The math might be a bit tricky to understand, but Im quite certain that its right. What Im not sure of is which kind of optimization function I should use. Also, would minimizing over something else (more parameters for example) than just alpha generate more accurate values?

Thanks in advance!

* EDIT ****

Ok, so this is how I create my synthetic data. I create random quaternions (4D vector representation of rotations) for R1 and then add a delay and a rotation (Rtrans) for R2.

```
def create_random_quaternion():

    v = np.zeros(4)
    v[0] = random.random()
    v[1] = random.random()
    v[2] = random.random()
    v[3] = random.random()

    return v / np.linalg.norm(v)


def create_synthetic_gyro_sequence(sequence_length):

    q = np.zeros((sequence_length, 4))
    ts = np.zeros(sequence_length)
    for i in range(sequence_length):
        q[i] = create_random_quaternion()
        ts[i] = 0.01*i

    return q, ts


def create_synthetic_data(l):

    gyro_data, gyro_ts = create_synthetic_gyro_sequence(l)
    camera_data = np.zeros((l/5,3,3))
    camera_ts = np.zeros(l/5)
    i = 0

    for n in range(l):

        if n % 5 == 0:
            camera_data[i] = Rtrans.dot(SLERP.quat2rot(gyro_data[n]))
            camera_ts[i] = 0.004+0.01*n
            i += 1

    return gyro_data, gyro_ts, camera_data, camera_ts
```

Comment: when you created your synthetic data, did you keep them in different coordinate systems too? It would be nice if you could post how do R1 and R2 look like...

Comment: Are `R1` and `R2` actual `numpy.matrix` objects? Because `R` isn't; if `R1` or `R2` isn't either, you may have a problem.

Comment: I've edited my original post. I didnt mention anything about quaternions before because i didn't want to involve more math than necessary.

Comment: Why do you interpolate R1? If you have more samples in R1 than R2 then I'd have thought it's R2 that you have to interpolate. Or am I talking out of my arse again? :)

Comment: Im interpolating R1 because the time delay might not be exactly a certain amount of samples. Since interpolation is just an approximation between two samples, I'd say you would want to interpolare the set with the most dense sampling.

Comment: Ah I see, so you're interpolating the sample of R1 that is closest to a given sample of R2 in order to get the R1 value at the same time. Got it. Have you tried a meta-heuristic like optimize.anneal? Havebn't studied the problem, but maybe fmin gets stuck in a local minimum?

Comment: Exactly! I have never heard of that. I'll give it a go. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: This is an interesting question. Once you have your solution, do not hesitate to answer yourself here :)

Comment: Well, I managed to partially solve my problem. I got it to work with my synthetic data by only using quaternions in the cost function. I get pretty accurate results, even when I add some amount of noise.

I does not yet work with my real data though. I'm not sure why yet. The only two reasons I can think of is either too much noise or I'm doing somethign wrong when I calculate the rotations from raw sensor data.

Comment: If your data is noisy then your solution is not going to be convex so fmin is going to be sensitive to initialization as it is a gradient-based optimization. If time isn't an issue you could try lots of random restarts and take the best. Alternatively you could try some kind of noise reduction / smoothing prior to your use of fmin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

The cost function is not correct. I'll try to explain if anyone is interested. The mapping of a point x between two coordinate systems can be written

x' = Qx

Now let R and R' be the same rotation expressed in the two different coordinate systems. A rotation by R followed by a transformation Q

x'' = QRx

Rotate the point back in its new coordinate system (For a rotation matrix, the transpose is the same as the inverse)

x' = R'^T QRx

As a final step, transform the point back to its original coordinate system

x = Q^T R'^T QRx

The correct cost function should be

Q^T R'^T QR

i.e. I forgot the Q^T